# rpmbuild missing from rhel 6.3

Tags: rhel6, rpm

I have a fresh new RHEL 6.3. I cannot access internet and because of this I cannot use `yum`. I would like to use the RPMs I get from the Red Hat package (2 discs full or RPMS).

These are all files `.src.rpm`. Once I issue a call to

```
rpm -vv -Uvh package.src.rpm
```

I can see the 2 folders

```
rpmbuild/SOURCES
rpmbuild/SPECS
```

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/127976/install-src-rpm-package-on-red-hat-linux) I should expect also folders BUILDS, RPMS, etc..
and I should be able to call `rpmbuild` on the spec file.

I don't have a `rpmbuild` tool installed and I don't have the other folders mentioned in the URL.

Am I using the right `rpm` command or do I need some other tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you continue, it would be a good idea to fix your Internet connectivity issues.

Anyway, `rpmbuild` is provided by the `rpm-build` package. Install that RPM (and any of its dependencies).

Comment: Oh dear.I didn't get it..I can install rpm-build if I don't have rpmbuild iteself?

Comment: Connect to the internet or use your RHEL DVD.

Answer (score 2):

Well you need rpm-build package for rpmbuild. Without it installing src rpm will only create SOURCES and SPECS where it will put .tgz source archive in SOURCES folder and SPEC file into /SPECS. All other folders are created temporarily  BUILD, BUILDROOT and apparently RPM is not there as you need to build it.